# mapView in ios 9 simulator is blank

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios-simulator, mapkit

Facing an issue using xcode v7.2.1 and the ios simulator v9.2 . 
The problem i'm facing is that the map appears blank when i run the application. 
The grid lines appear for a second and then it's just blank. I've tried searching for a solution but haven't found any that have worked.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet var map: MKMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    //maps integration
    let longitude : CLLocationDegrees =  17.486374
    let latitude : CLLocationDegrees = 78.543345
    let longDelta : CLLocationDegrees = 0.1
    let latDelta : CLLocationDegrees = 0.1
    let location : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
    let span : MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, longDelta)
    let region : MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)
    map.setRegion(region, animated: true)




}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

[it's just a picture of the simulator once the app is run. 
This is what i meant when i said blank incase it wasn't clear.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcQEG.png)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I think it's possible you may have confused your latitude and longitude values. The lat/long you have now takes you to Svalbard and Jan Mayen (a couple of remote islands in the middle of nowhere, north of Norway), but if you switch the lat and long you get Hyderabad in India.

Comment: Your span is too small. Try: 0.155 for both latDelta and 0.26 for longDelta. If it doesn't work, try increasing the values. It will render. But with the span you are supplying now, it's zoomed in so much that it looks blank. I've just tested this.

Comment: @DrBeardface Thanks a lot..that worked. But even if it's remote islands why is it blank ? Is it because they're unmapped ?

Comment: @rohanKumar It seems that on the iPhone 6 (9.2) simulator the lines stay, but on other simulators like 6 Plus (9.2), 6s (9.2), and 6s Plus (9.2) the lines disappear. Strange. (Also on 5s (9.2) the lines disappear apparently.)

Comment: @DrBeardFace the lines come for a second and disappear on all the simulators I tried (including iPhone 6 (9.2)). it's basically the same behaviour across the simulators for me... i wonder why this happens. I'm using xcode 7.2.1.
I'm a noob in this as of now so i don't know if the xcode version makes a difference. 
I'd also appreciate a few pointers on how to get the best out of the documentation. A lot of it uses jargon and I find that difficult to decipher. Any thing you can think of ?

Comment: @rohanKumar Hmm, weird. That's not the same behavior I'm getting, although I am using Xcode 7.3. However, I highly doubt the Xcode version makes a difference. As far as understanding the docs, all I can really say is just take your time to understand the jargon. If you come across something you don't understand, take some time to put aside the thing you were trying to do and instead really focus on researching and understanding that jargon. Otherwise, reading the docs will probably be mostly a waste of time. That's all I can really think of... Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: @DrBeardface Thanks a lot :)
Also seeing as you've commented the solution to me, there's no way to accept it here. I'm leaving this the way it is if there isn't anything else to do. Usually have to accept an answer right? Either way, thanks folks for everything :)

Comment: @rohanKumar You're welcome! Yeah, I should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's possible you may have confused your latitude and longitude values. The lat/long you have now takes you to Svalbard and Jan Mayen (a couple of remote islands in the middle of nowhere, north of Norway), but if you switch the lat and long you get Hyderabad in India.

Answer (score 0):

Just Print the Value.
it might be 0,0 and your location would be on the sea.
please make sure that your location have valid location. longitude and latitude.

This case always happen when you trying to update the map on ViewDidload instead of view Didappear.